# How can we detect which users have performed which operations in GCS (Google Cloud Storage)?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Using access logging, as detailed here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs, we can download and analyze usage patterns for our data. However, looking at the actual data, I noticed that there is no data relating which user (or service-account) performed the operation. The closest seeming attribute in the usage logs as described here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#format is the cs_user_agent attribute. However, this attribute seems to describe more about the tool performing the access (i.e., gsutil or gcloud) rather than the user.

Is it possible to obtain information that relates the activity to a user/service-account? Perhaps using the s_request_id attribute?

Is there a technical reason this is missing? Or is it intended as a privacy-preserving mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about the access log schema in our [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#format). `cs_user_agent` tells you what kind of program made the request, while `s_request_id` is a unique id for the request. The closest thing to what you need would be `c_ip`, which is the IP address of the machine making the request. You could possibly tie those to users. If this doesn't suffice, you could have your clients make requests only through some code you yourself have written which will log - in parallel to sending the request - the URL, method, any headers / metadata desired, and the user / account making the request.

Comment: <sigh>. Sadly, this does not address the need. However, I accept the fact that the information is basically missing and that there is no reasonable way to obtain it without a c_ip -> user/account map. Consider this an enhancement request. :)

Comment: Yep, exactly, you'll need a c_ip -> user/account map, heh. This isn't impossible but has edge cases depending on a bunch of factors... Feel free to file any and all feature requests in [issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com)!